# GLSL reflect function math correct?

Tags: glsl, mathematics, vectors

In the documentation of [GLSL - reflect](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/reflect.xhtml) given a surface normal $N$ and an incident vector $I$ the calculation being performed is reported as
$$
\text{reflect}(I,N) = I - 2\text{dot}(I,N)N
$$

I wonder if this math is correct because in my calculations the sign should be swapped.

Can anyone confirm?

Maybe if $I$ is not incident but outgoing from the point of application the sign would be swapped?

Comment: This question pops up from time to time here, the math is correct.